# NHAPI 2.5.1 VXU missing RXA segment

Tags: .net, hl7, nhapi

It appears that NHAPI VXU_V04 (Unsolicited Vaccination Record Update) class is missing support for the RXA segment (Pharmacy/Treatment Administration) for 2.5.1 version of HL7.

Am I somehow choosing the wrong class for VXU?

```
VXU_V04 vxu = new VXU_V04();
vxu.MSH - works
vxu.PID - works
no vxu.RXA???
```

Gina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to add an Order first. Then on the Order you can add the RXA segment.

```
        VXU_V04 vxu = new VXU_V04();
        var order = vxu.AddORDER();
        var rxa = order.RXA;
        rxa.AdministeredAmount.Value = "xxx";
```

Geez NHapi is a tough act to figure out. I would pay for a reasonable commercial library. ;)

Gina